# QDataStream запись несколько QVector в один файл и загрузка обратно

Tags: c++, qt

В данный момент в программе реализовано сохранение изагрузка одного массива **QVector**.

Подскажите как реализовать сохранение нескольких массивов в один файл. Вообще поддерживает ли **QDataStream**?
Если записать подряд два массива

```
QVector <SP> h;
QVector <SP> r; либо иного типа

   //Запись
    QFile file(filepath);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
       QDataStream write(&file);
       write.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_13);

       qDebug() << "Записываем файл";
       qDebug() << "Размер массива r = " << r.size();
       qDebug() << "Размер массива h = " << h.size()

       write << r; // Сливаем весь массив в файл 
       write << h;

       if(write.status() != QDataStream::Ok)
       {
           qDebug() << "Ошибка записи";
       }
       file.close(); 
     } 
//чтение
QFile file(filepath);
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
 QDataStream read(&file);
 read.setVersion (QDataStream::Qt_5_13);
 QVector<SP> temp;
 read >> temp;
 qDebug() << "Читаем файл";
 qDebug() << "Размер массива temp = " << temp.size();
```

Записываем файл

Размер массива r =  1

Размер массива h =  1

Читаем файл

Размер массива temp =  1

файл соответственно перезаписывается и в нем хранятся данные ПЕРВОГО r массива.
Если возможно сохранять подряд несколько массивов то как считывать эти отрезки массивов в файле?

Comment: Тут скидывали статью https://habr.com/ru/post/150827/
В ней нет записи двух контейнеров, только аналогично один.
И я так понимаю .writeRawData(any.array,sizeof(any.array)); для QVector не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
write << r << h; 

QVector<SP_5_pril_u> temp;
QVector<SP_5_pril_u> temp2;
read >> temp >>temp2;
```

все работает, обьекты живые в том же виде что и были до сохранения.

Comment: А если в них были указатели ?

Comment: так по ним сохраняешь и на них же обратно вешаешь, вроде все должно работать.

Comment: Все работает когда у вас есть операторы `<<` и `>>` для записи/чтения объектов пользовательских классов (`SP_5_pril_u`) в/из `QDataStream`. Если у вас их нет - ничего не работает.